# I can`t get acces to myArray

Tags: objective-c

XCode is new for me and I have simple question. Help me please...
I can`t get acces to myArray in this situation:

```
-(void)viewdidload{
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(IBAction) ..... {
//Here i need to use myArray. And i can`t. How can I do this???
}
```

Comment: use @property in your class

Comment: @Pavel, this is very basic question. Perhaps you should seek out some tutorials first. I recommend the one from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a property. In order achieve this, add

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

to `@interface` block of your class. Then, you can access the array as `self.myArray` inside your class.

Please see [Ry's guide](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html) for more info on properties.

PS: For the sake of best practices, you should read about encapsulating your data as well. [Apple's own guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) is great for learning about encapsulation with objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a variable throughout different methods in your class, you must have an instance variable.

The easiest option is with a `@property` as Ayberk's answer suggests.

You can also create private instance variables at the beginning of your `@implementation` declaration.

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSMutableArray *_myArray;
}
```

Now you can access `_myArray` in every method in your class.

Please note that I HIGHLY recommend using a `@property`.  I'm only adding my answer for completeness.